# Postfix unable to authenticate with Microsoft Exchange (No credentials were supplied)

Tags: centos, postfix, sasl, exchange-2016

I want to setup postfix on my nagios server to relay emails to our Microsoft Exchange server and I am running into issues with authenticating with Microsoft Exchange.

Specifically I am getting this error:

> warning: SASL authentication failure: GSSAPI Error: No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible (No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KCM:))

I have the cyrus-sasl packages installed

**[root@nag postfix]# yum list installed | grep sas**

```
cyrus-sasl.x86_64                                2.1.27-17.el9                         @baseos
cyrus-sasl-gssapi.x86_64                         2.1.27-17.el9                         @anaconda
cyrus-sasl-lib.x86_64                            2.1.27-17.el9                         @anaconda
cyrus-sasl-md5.x86_64                            2.1.27-17.el9                         @appstream
cyrus-sasl-plain.x86_64                          2.1.27-17.el9                         @anaconda
```

**[root@nag postfix]# postconf -df | grep sasl**

```
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
cyrus_sasl_config_path =
lmtp_sasl_auth_cache_name =
lmtp_sasl_auth_cache_time = 90d
lmtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
lmtp_sasl_auth_soft_bounce = yes
lmtp_sasl_mechanism_filter =
lmtp_sasl_password_maps =
lmtp_sasl_path =
lmtp_sasl_security_options = noplaintext, noanonymous
lmtp_sasl_tls_security_options = $lmtp_sasl_security_options
lmtp_sasl_tls_verified_security_options = $lmtp_sasl_tls_security_options
lmtp_sasl_type = cyrus
    $lmtp_sasl_password_maps $lmtp_tls_policy_maps $mailbox_command_maps
    $smtp_pix_workaround_maps $smtp_sasl_password_maps $smtp_tls_policy_maps
proxy_write_maps = $smtp_sasl_auth_cache_name $lmtp_sasl_auth_cache_name
send_cyrus_sasl_authzid = no
smtp_sasl_auth_cache_name =
smtp_sasl_auth_cache_time = 90d
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtp_sasl_auth_soft_bounce = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter =
smtp_sasl_password_maps =
smtp_sasl_path =
smtp_sasl_security_options = noplaintext, noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtp_sasl_security_options
smtp_sasl_tls_verified_security_options = $smtp_sasl_tls_security_options
smtp_sasl_type = cyrus
    {permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination}}
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks =
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_response_limit = 12288
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_service = smtp
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
```

**main.cf**

```
compatibility_level = 2
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = host.domain.tld
mydomain = domain.tld
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/24, 1.1.1.0/24
relayhost = [relayhost.domain.tld]:587
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
home_mailbox = Maildir/
 
  
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/README_FILES
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/pki/tls/certs
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
shlib_directory = /usr/lib64/postfix
myhostname = host.domain.tld
relayhost = [relayhost.domain.tld]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
```

**[root@nag postfix]# systemctl status postfix**

```
 postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-12-14 14:05:42 NST; 8min ago
    Process: 29028 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 29030 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 29031 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 29099 (master)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 11100)
     Memory: 4.9M
        CPU: 331ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
             ├─29099 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
             ├─29100 pickup -l -t unix -u
             ├─29101 qmgr -l -t unix -u
             └─29148 tlsmgr -l -t unix -u

Dec 14 14:07:02 host.domain.tld postfix/pickup[29100]: C4AF631A2671: uid=0 from=<host@domain.tld>
Dec 14 14:07:02 host.domain.tld postfix/trivial-rewrite[29146]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 758: overriding earlier entry: myhostname=host.domain.tld
Dec 14 14:07:02 host.domain.tld postfix/cleanup[29145]: C4AF631A2671: message-id=<20211214173702.OJWqL%host@domain.tld>
Dec 14 14:07:02 host.domain.tld postfix/qmgr[29101]: C4AF631A2671: from=<host@domain.tld>, size=330, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 14 14:07:02 host.domain.tld postfix/smtp[29147]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 758: overriding earlier entry: myhostname=host.domain.tld
Dec 14 14:07:02 host.domain.tld postfix/tlsmgr[29148]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 758: overriding earlier entry: myhostname=host.domain.tld
Dec 14 14:07:03 host.domain.tld postfix/smtp[29147]: warning: SASL authentication failure: GSSAPI Error: No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible (No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KCM:))
Dec 14 14:07:03 host.domain.tld postfix/bounce[29150]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 758: overriding earlier entry: myhostname=host.domain.tld
Dec 14 14:07:03 host.domain.tld postfix/smtp[29147]: C4AF631A2671: to=<test.user@domain.tld>, relay=mail.domain.tld[1.1.1.2]:587, delay=0.29, delays=0.01/0.07/0.21/0, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (SASL authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server mail.domain.tld[1.1.1.2]: generic failure)
Dec 14 14:07:25 host.domain.tld postfix/showq[29198]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 758: overriding earlier entry: myhostname=host.domain.tld
```

**sasl_passwd**

```
[relayhost.domain.tld]:587 user@domain.tld:bestpassword
```

**[root@nag postfix]# mailq**

```
mailq: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 758: overriding earlier entry: myhostname=host.domain.tld
postqueue: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 758: overriding earlier entry: myhostname=host.domain.tld
-Queue ID-  --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
C4AF631A2671     330 Tue Dec 14 14:07:02  user@domain.tld
(SASL authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server relayhost.domain.tld[1.1.1.2]: generic failure)
                                         test.user@domain.tld
```

---

**EDIT**

I found out what the issue was. This question answered it [How to configure Postfix client relay to Exchange 2010 server](https://serverfault.com/questions/188469/how-to-configure-postfix-client-relay-to-exchange-2010-server?rq=1)

I added **smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = !gssapi, !ntlm, static:rest** to the **main.cf**